# Execute ajax every second when ajax request successfully finished

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can somebody help me, I want to execute ajax every second when ajax request successfully finished, my problem is that the ajax continue execute even it is not yet ready.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        process();
        function process(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/AjaxAvailableSeats",
                async: false,
                success: function (d) {
                    //alert(f_code);
                    $('#available_seatResult').html(d);
                    setTime();
                },
                error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                    alert(errorObj.toString());
                }
            })
        }
        function setTime(){
            setTimeout(process, 1000);
        }
});
```

Comment: I think **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** is what you need. *"Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID."*

Comment: @RamisWachtler, `setInterval` should not used here. `setTimeout` works fine as it will be invoked after completion of ajaxRequest every time, and cycle is created.

Comment: I find that the function is invoked repeatedly, I don't see any problem with the code. The question is not clear. What do you mean by 'the ajax continue execute even it is not yet ready'?

Answer (score 0):

```
process();

function process() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AjaxAvailableSeats",
        async: false,
        success: setInterval(function () {
            process();
        }, 1000),
        error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

you only call the function itself on success again with a delay of 1 second (1000 ms)

Comment: I don't see any no difference at the time of run between this code and the one posted by OP.

Comment: @GaneshKumar I forgot to replace setTimeout with setInteral, will edit

Answer (score 0):

this will execute the next ajax only if the prev one has finished:

```
function process(){
     return $.ajax({ .... });
}

var request = process();

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == "200"){
        request = process();
    }else if(request.status != "200"){
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("ajax error");
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, It seems really works very smooth on my local, but when I put in on my Live, its still the same.

Comment: ve you tryed to console log request just before the if?? oh and remove the async false